# Different solution to system of nonlinear second order ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the system of the following two ODEs

$$0=\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} \Phi_i''\left(x\right)+\left(\mu-\tilde{K} \Phi_1'(x)-\tilde{K} \Phi_2'(x)\right)\ \Phi_i'\left(x\right)-\delta \Phi_{i}\left(x\right)+\left(x-\rho\right)^2+\frac{\tilde{K}}{2} \Phi_i'(x)^2$$

where $\sigma>0,\mu\in\mathbb{R},\tilde{K}\geq 0,\delta>0,\rho\in\mathbb{R},i\in\{1,2\}$,
I have shown that there exists one solution for both ODEs and they agree, namely a polynomial of second order with coefficients in decreasing order

$$
p=\frac{\sqrt{\delta^2+12\tilde{K}}-\delta}{6\tilde{K}}\\
q=-\frac{2\rho+\frac{\mu\left(\delta-\sqrt{\delta^2+12\tilde{K}}\right)}{3\tilde{K}}}{\frac{\delta+\sqrt{\delta^2+12\tilde{K}}}{2}}\\
r=\frac{\sigma^{2} p+\mu q-\frac{3}{4} \tilde{K}q^2+\rho^{2}}{\delta}.
$$
The desired functions shall solve the ODEs in a closed interval $[a,b]$.

Are there anysolutions to this restricted problem and how can they be quantified / found when imposing the restrictions that

- $\Phi_1$ shall be convex (in $[a,b]$)
- $\Phi_2(\alpha)=\Phi_2(a),\Phi_2(\beta)=\Phi_2(b)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are determined via $\Phi_1(\alpha)=-c$ and $\Phi_1(\beta)=d$ for two fixed real numbers $c,d\geq 0$.

Any help / tips on approaching this problem are welcome!